# If variable is equal to value or another value - javascript

Tags: javascript, list, if-statement

I'm trying to write a simple Pig Latin code. I want to check if the first letter of the input string is a vowel, if so then to run that certain code. How can I ask if y is equal to one of those values.

```
function pigLatin() {
    var y = prompt("Enter a word:")
    if (y.charAt(0) = a,e,i,o,u) {
        var pigLatin = y + "ay";
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Answer is: " + pigLatin;
    } else {
        var wordLength = y.length + 1;
        var pigLatin = y.substring(1, wordLength) + y.charAt(0) + "ay";
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Answer is: " + pigLatin;
    }
}
```

Comment: = assigns, == or === checks for equality (apart from the invalid syntax a,e,i,o,u)

Comment: Please see [**Equality comparisons**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: Possible duplicate of several SO posts in relation to equality of which one is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (y.charAt(0) = a,e,i,o,u) {
```

...is not valid.

Try...

```
if ('aeiou'.includes(y.charAt(0))) {
```

Your problems are...

- Strings must be quoted, even if they're only one character long.
- An array must be wrapped with `[` and `]` (unless constructed via another means such as with the `Array` constructor)
- You can't use the assignment operator (`=`), nor any equivalency operator (`==` or `===`) to automatically check for the presence of an item in an array. Since you're checking against a list of single characters, you can directly use `String.prototype.includes()` on it.

If the user cancels the [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), you will get `null` also, which you are not handling (it will crash on the condition mentioned).

Comment: Or perhaps `if ('aeiou'.includes(y.charAt(0))) {`.

Comment: @Rajesh That regular expression is wrong. Maybe you meant `/[aeiou]/`? (I'd argue this is a bad use case for a regular expression anyway.)

Comment: @Rajesh While it could work, I don't see the need to use a regex over normal string methods

Comment: This is the first time asking a question on here. You guys are amazing people <3

Answer (score 0):

First, you need the letters to be in quotes in this

```
if (y.charAt(0) = a,e,i,o,u)
```

Second, use `===` for equals.

Third you want it to be one of the vowels 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'.

You could compare the `indexOf` the char against -1:

```
if (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(y.charAt(0)) !== -1)
//...
```

Comment: `in` doesn't work like that. It checks for keys in an object, here you have an array of chars.

Comment: Of course; that gets an index.. the other answer is better anyway.